# Getting the child control (i.e. TextBox) of an ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In MFC i can get the it using the following method:

```
textbox = CWnd::GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
```

How can i directly access the textbox control of a combobox in C#, so that i can do the following:

```
textbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099133/right-justified-combobox-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Nick. I already read this post. I still need to set textbox aliging to right. The implementation you suggest only affects the aligning of list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible in WinForms.

but you can btain the Horizontal-Alignment functionality by setting `ComboBox1.RightToLeft` To  `RightToLeft.Yes`.

Comment: well it also moves the arrow to left.

Comment: True. You need to either write own ComboBOx class, or abandon the WinForms, and work with more efficient UI platform like WPF.