# How to format a specific item in the ComboBox in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have code similar to this in a method that (re)creates the columns in the DataGridView:

```
MyColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "..",
    HeaderText = "..",
    SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
};       
MyColumn.Items.Clear();
foreach (string s in MyStringList)
{
    MyColumn.Items.Add(s);
}
MyColumn.Items.Add(""); 
// I would like this empty string to be shown as "No group" 
// with an italic grayed out font
```

I think that I probably must create a class for the items of the ComboBox-es in the column, in which I should override the `ToString()` method, but I want to know how to format the `No Group` item.

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1790199/258462) which is a about a normal ComboBox not inside a DataGridView, with the answer solving the problem using the `DrawMode` prperty and `DrawItem` event of the `ComboBox` class.

Comment: Why not `MyColumn.Items.Add("No Group");` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the question with "No Group" as the text that I want to format.

Comment: `MyColumn.DisplayStyle` is `DropDownButton` so you should be able to use `ComboBoxRenderer` class for `DrawDropDownButton` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486187/2516718

Comment: @derloopkat Thank you. This solves my problem partially, but I am looking for a way to paint the drop-down menus of the ComboBox-es inside a ComboBox column, besides the painting of the closed ComboBox-es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom-painting the `ComboBox`, you need to handle `EditingControlShowing` and then get the `EditingControl` which is `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` and then set its `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and handle its `DrawItem` event.

For custom-painting the cell, you need to handle `CellPainting` event and set different font and color for the cell styles and let the paint continue with new values. You can also paint the whole cell if you want.

[image]

**Example**

*Load Sample Data:*

```
private DataTable LoadProducts()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("CategoryId", typeof(int));
    dt.Rows.Add("P1", 1);
    dt.Rows.Add("P2", 1);
    dt.Rows.Add("P3", DBNull.Value);
    return dt;
}
private DataTable LoadCategories()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, "No Category");
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "C1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "C2");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "C3");
    return dt;
}
```

*Setup DataGridView Columnms:*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var products = LoadProducts();
    var categories = LoadCategories();

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "NameColumn",
        DataPropertyName = "Name",
        HeaderText = "Name"
    });
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    {
        Name = "CategoryIdColumn",
        DataPropertyName = "CategoryId",
        HeaderText = "Category",
        DataSource = categories,
        ValueMember = "Id",
        DisplayMember = "Name",
        DisplayStyle= DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
    });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = products;
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
    dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;
}
```

*Handle EditingControlShowing*

```
private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1?.CurrentCell?.OwningColumn?.Name != "CategoryIdColumn")
        return;
    var combo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (combo == null)
        return;

    combo.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    combo.DrawItem += (obj, args) =>
    {
        var txt = args.Index >= 0 ? combo.GetItemText(combo.Items[args.Index]) : "";
        var textColor = args.Index == 0 ? SystemColors.GrayText : SystemColors.ControlText;
        var font = args.Index == 0 ? new Font(combo.Font, FontStyle.Italic) : combo.Font;
        if ((args.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            textColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        }
        args.DrawBackground();
        TextRenderer.DrawText(args.Graphics, txt, font,
            args.Bounds, textColor,
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);
    };
}
```

*Handle CellPainting*

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 ||
            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "CategoryIdColumn")
        return;
    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == DBNull.Value)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
    }
    else
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
}
```